# Phase transtions. Why has Ehrenfest classification been replaced by modern classification?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

Why did modern classification replace Ehrenfest classification? What are the advantages of the modern one?

Comment: It is both too precise (would the difference between a, say, 14th order transition and a 15th order transition really be relevant?), and too restrictive (there are phase transitions that can't be described in this framework, the most famous example being the Kosterlitz-Thouless phase transition, at which the free energy is infinitely differentiable but not analytic).

Answer (score 1):

Because in nature there are phase transitions which are not characterized by a jump of any n-th derivative of a fundamental equation (thermodynamic potential) but by other non-analytic behavior. For example, the 2D Ising model at zero external magnetic field, where everything can be worked out analytically, has a logarithmic divergence of the specific heat as leading non-analytic behavior and not a discontinuity of specific heat.

As stated at the beginning, the advantage is to adhere to the exact mathematical characterization of the non-analytic behavior.